# Spring Batch: reuse existing service as a reader

Tags: jpa, transactions, spring-batch

I want to reuse an existing, transactional,paginated service class, which retrieves the items using JPA from a database, inside a Spring batch job, as a reader. I want to do that instead of using directly the JpaPagingItemReader basically because the JPA query is more complex to build and the service already provides this functionality.

My question would be what are the things I should take into account when developing the Spring batch adapter over this service. Although the reference documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#pagingItemReaders has a section on reusing existing services, it doesn't say anything regarding the constraints, if there are any, of using such a transactional service.

Now, I looked at the JpaPagingItemReader as an example for building the reader, and I came up with a couple of questions I couldn't find answers for netiher in the documentation or on stackoverflow, although this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/26549831/4473261 helped.

The first thing I noticed is that a new transaction is used by the JpaPagingItemReader for reading a page of data. The above post says that this new transaction is needed "so that features like retry and skip can be correctly performed.". I have also found this article related to the matter https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/03/transactions-in-spring-batch-part-3-skip-and-retry/ that says that "when a skippable exception occurs during reading, we just increase the skip count and keep the exception for a later call on the onSkipInRead method of the SkipListener, if configured. There’s no rollback". So I assume that the reader has to do any reading of the records in a new transaction so that if a rollback of the transaction started when the processing of the chunk began happened, then the reader is not affected. I am wondering if this is true and if in this case my adapter should create a new transaction, invoke the service inside that transaction and then commit the transaction, similarly to how the JpaPagingItemReader does it. If that's true though, I wonder why there isn't any template provided by the framework which creates the transaction, delegates to the service the actual call to retrieve the data and then commits the transaction.

Greetings,
Cristi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a reader perspective, there really isn't much to be concerned about.  You can see in our `JmsItemReader` which obviously works with a transactional store that we don't take any additional precautions within the `ItemReader` itself.

What really matters is how you configure your step.  When configuring your step, you'll need to mark the reader as transactional so that Spring Batch handles rollback correctly.  When Spring Batch reads items in a fault tollerant step, the default behavior is to buffer them so that they won't be re-read on failure (retry, skip, etc).  However, since the items read from a transactional store are tied to the transaction (and therefore reset when the rollback occurs), you need to tell Spring Batch to not buffer the items as they are read.

To mark the `ItemReader` as transactional, you'll set the not-quite-well-named flag `is-reader-transactional-queue` to true.  You can read more about configuring steps and transactions in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html

Comment: Is there any way if we can reused Reader and Processor of any step ?

Comment: @Pra_A Please open up another question and we can answer it there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63296065/how-to-override-spring-batch-compositeitemwriter-manage-transaction-for-delegate - created the question here. Please guide.