# Override Spring-Batch's RepositoryItemReader to reset page to 0

Tags: java, spring-batch

In a spring-batch program I have a problem that is related to [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59607950/while-readingthrough-repositoryitemreader-and-writing-in-same-table-some-items/67840608#67840608). That is, I am updating a column that is in the where clause of the select statement.

For a suggested solution in that post, adding a new column to the database is not an option for me.

Another suggested solution would be to emulate the `JpaPagingItemReader` by overriding the `getPage()` method. This would entail resetting the page variable to 0.

What is the equivalent variable or technique for `RepositoryItemReader`?

Comment: This "emulation" technique is not the way to go IMO and I'm not sure it even works. Is using a cursor-based reader an option for you?

Comment: I will implement JpaPagingItemReader instead. Can data repository classes be called by JpaPagingItemReader? My application has several repositories that I would like to reuse.