# Spring Batch - MongoItemReader not reading all records

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-batch

I created a Spring Batch job which reads orders from MongoDB and makes a rest call to upload them. However, the batch job automatically gets completed even though all records are not read by MongoItemReader.

I am maintaining a field batchProcessed:boolean on Orders collection. The MongoItemReader reads records for which {batchProcessed:{$ne:true}} as I need to run the batch job multiple times but not process the same documents again and again.

In my OrderWriter I set batchProcessed to true.

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public MongoItemReader<Order> orderReader() {
     MongoItemReader<Order> reader = new MongoItemReader<>();
     reader.setTemplate(mongoTemplate);

     HashMap<String,Sort.Direction> sortMap = new HashMap<>();
     sortMap.put("_id",Direction.ASC);
     reader.setSort(sortMap);

     reader.setTargetType(Order.class);
     reader.setQuery("{batchProcessed:{$ne:true}}");
     return reader;
}

@Bean
public Step uploadOrdersStep(OrderItemProcessor processor)  {
     return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                              .<Order, Order>chunk(1)
                              .reader(orderReader())
                              .processor(processor)
                              .writer(orderWriter)
                              .build();
}

@Bean
public Job orderUploadBatchJob(JobBuilderFactory factory,
                               OrderItemProcessor processor) {
      return factory.get("uploadOrder")
                    .flow(uploadOrdersStep(processor))
                    .end()
                    .build();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MongoItemReader` is a paging item reader. When reading items in pages and changing items that might be returned by the query (ie a field that is used in the query's "where" clause), the paging logic can be lost and some items might be skipped. There's a similar problem with the JPA paging item reader that is explained in details here: [Spring batch jpaPagingItemReader why some rows are not read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26509971/spring-batch-jpapagingitemreader-why-some-rows-are-not-read)

Common techniques to work around this issue is to use a cursor-based reader, use a staging table/collection, use a partitioned step with a partition per page, etc.

Comment: Thank you @Mahmoud, I a exploring cursor based reader.