# spring batch read and write same table

Tags: spring-batch, java-17

I’m using spring batch to read chunk data in a table, send event and when event is send change boolean value in writer.

exemple:

My reader (RepositoryItemReader) call a JpaRepository that retrieve all line that are with status not sent like this

```
Page<Item> findbynotsent();
```

The process send notification and set the sent value to true if all is ok

The writer save Item in bdd to pass the sent value to true

But when the reader do the second loop he missed many lines because the writer has change the state condition.
so when the reader play the sql request the second time he get the second page. But in reality the second page is the third page of the first request and springBatch missed one page. I think its because of limit … offset …

Does exist another solution to achieve this simple case? Do you have another implements that i can use?

Thanks for help

Comment: When you're doing the find, you don't seem to specify which ones you want. Perhaps you should try: findByNotSentOrderByIdAsc. Additionally, it may be more efficient to use a Slice rather than a Page (if you don't need `getTotalElements` or `getTotalPages`). So: `Slice<Item> findByNotSentOrderByIdAsc();`.

Answer (score 0):

Paging readers do not cope well with changing the search criteria in item processors or writers. Here are some related posts:

- [Spring Batch ItemReader skips the first record on the second page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68744338/spring-batch-itemreader-skips-the-first-record-on-the-second-page)
- [RepositoryItemReader skipping items in Spring Batch V5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76543864/repositoryitemreader-skipping-items-in-spring-batch-v5)
- [Spring batch jpaPagingItemReader why some rows are not read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26509971/spring-batch-jpapagingitemreader-why-some-rows-are-not-read)

You either need to not change the search criteria in the same step, or use a cursor-based reader (which should work without issues in these cases).